# Is there a way to register hotkeys in a Universal Windows App? Lost functionality when converting from 4.5 to UWP

Tags: c#, .net, hook, win-universal-app, hotkeys

I had hotkeys setup by using Windows. Input and hooks, but it seems Universal Windows apps don't let you do it. All libraries I try in Nuget fail and I can't seem to use the same method of using hWnd, RegisterHotKey, and hooks.

Did UWP remove this functionality?

Comment: Hooks and global hotkeys are not supported in universal Windows apps.

Comment: @RaymondChen seems like a giant leap backwards to me

Comment: The universal app model is intentionally conservative. Letting apps install global hotkeys and hooks violates the principle of app isolation and would be a great step toward writing a keylogger. Also, there are no `hWnd`s in the universal app model, because Windows Phone, Xbox, and HoloLens don't have `hwnd`s.

Comment: @RaymondChen Are keyloggers a bigger concern over usability? Desktop apps should be fully functional with just a keyboard, no mouse, no touch interface.  Has Microsoft completely forgotten about accessibility and ergonomics?

Comment: You can create hotkeys for use within your app. But global hotkeys are not available at the moment. You can ask for them, maybe you'll get them. (You could also ask for HWNDs, but that's not going to do as well seeing as HWNDs exist only on desktop, not universally.)